# extracting data from a sql query

Tags: java, jdbc

IF I have a query like:

Then while doing it, should I write each entry from the table to get the output. like

Now How I get all the entries of my table flight. I have 2 columns in it..

Comment: Don't be shy. Use ctrl+K to format you code when posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both columns are having `String/Varchar` type.

```
List<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();
while(rs.next()){
    Flight flight = new Flight();
    flight.setColumn1(rs.getString(1));   // Its better to use column name instead to avoid any unexpected bug
    flight.setColumn2(rs.getString(2));   // Its better to use column name instead to avoid any unexpected bug 
}
```

P.S. Its better to specify columns to fetch in your query, i.e. `select COL1, COL2,... from....`

Comment: For your solution, using indexing on `getString` requires that the developer lists all relevant columns in the SQL. The `SELECT *` type SQL will never work for indexing retrieval.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: When one list out all the columns, as I myself suggested, then who needs indices to fetch the values. :)

Comment: @Adeel Ansari, true but listing all columns can be a long String whereas `SELECT *` is short and sweet :)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: But this sweet thing might make you toggle your IDE and SQL client back and forth every now and then, just to check the sequence of the columns. :)

Comment: @Shilps: There are methods available for all typical types, you mentioned. You just need to refer to the `ResultSet` API Docs.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari, hence why "SELECT *" is still preferred, you just need to retrieve the column by `rs.getString("flightNo")` instead of `rs.getString(1)` :)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: You got the point here. I myself prefer both, writing columns in query and get the values using column name. Because it just make it handy to exclude or concat some columns whenever seems befitting. And you sometime really need that for `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [ResultSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). Code can look like:

```
while (rs.next())
    {
    String fld1 = rs.getString("column_name1");
    int fld2 = rs.getInt("column_name2");
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a [ResultSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), you will have to iterate it in this manner:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
List<Flight> flightList = null;

try {
    String Query = "select * FROM flights WHERE flight_no=? ";
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1,"CSC585")
    rs = s.executeQuery();

    if (rs != null) {
        flightList = new ArrayList<Flight>();

        while (rs.next()) { //Moves the cursor from 1 to N
            flightList.add(mapResultSet(rs)); //Write your own mapper....
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {

} finally {
    //First close the ResultSet, then the PreparedStatement
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
            rs = null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }

    if (ps != null) {
        try {
            ps.close();
            ps = null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
}


Flight mapResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Flight flight = null;

    if (rs != null) {
        flight = new Flight();

        flight.setFlightNo(rs.getString("flight_no")); //Column Name as per your SQL table
    }

    return flight...
}
```

Bear in mind: Once you **finished** using your PreparedStatement and ResultSet, close your ResultSet **first** then your **PreparedStatement**/**Statement**.

Answer (score 0):

The most user-friendly (and least error-prone) way is probably to use Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate) abstraction:

Spring's own sample Code:

```
List<Actor> actors = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select first_name, last_name from t_actor",
        new RowMapper<Actor>() {
            public Actor mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{
                Actor actor = new Actor();
                actor.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                actor.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                return actor;
            }
        });
```